# Python - read - rewrite on a text file (Driving me crazy)

Tags: python

I am new in python, and I like it a lot so far. I would like to do the following task, but I have not been able to do it and it is driving me crazy.

I have a file1 which looks like this;

```
a b
c d
e f
```

and I file2 that look like this:

```
g
h
i
```

and I file3 that looks like this:

```
j
k
l
```

I would like to write file2 and file3 into file1, so file1 looks like this:

```
a  b  g  j
c  d  h  k
e  f  i  l
```

Basically coping the other files columns next to the current columns on file1. I understand that in order to do that, I have to read all files and then re-write file 1. I tried, but nothing works. Please, anyone show me how this code should looks like. Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is similar to [Jon Clements'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13662320/455276) answer, but different syntax:

```
with open('1.txt') as f1, open('2.txt') as f2, open('3.txt') as f3:
    for line in zip(f1,f2,f3):
        print ' '.join(e.strip() for e in line)
```

Prints:

```
a b g j
c d h k
e f i l
```

Answer (score 2):

Untested:

```
from itertools import izip

filenames = ['1.txt', '2.txt', '3.txt']
files = map(open, filenames)
for lines in izip(*files):
    print ''.join(i.strip() for i in lines)
```

Comment: You need to replace `''.join(i.strip() for i in lines)` with `' '.join(i.strip() for i in lines)` for it to produce the desired output. ie, add a space.  +1 tho

Comment: @thewolf thanks for the help. However, when I use print at the end it prints just fine. But if I "newfile.write('\t'.join(i.strip() for i in lines))" it writes all in one line...how can I fix this?

Comment: @JonClements thanks for the help. However, when I use print at the end it prints just fine. But if I "newfile.write('\t'.join(i.strip() for i in lines))" it writes all in one line...how can I fix this?

Comment: @henrymartinez You need to add a new line to it `'\t'.join(i.strip() for i in lines) + '\n')` (or use `print >> newfile, '\t'.join(i.strip() for i in lines)`

Comment: @henrymartinez You're welcome - on a sidenote - it wouldn't hurt you to go back over some of your old questions, and where you good answers - accept them... your accepted rating is low and as you know it's a thank you to someone that's spent time trying to help - and when it's low - people are reluctant to help... just a tip :)